# Unable to add <th> on an array of objects based on conditionals

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, html-table

I have this array of objects which I want to render from server side as an html5 table. I have two types of data in the array. So based on the values I want to create `tr td` and also add a `th` before each type of the data. Here's the array:

Array:

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'monica', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'chandler', type: 'B' },
  { name: 'joey', type: 'B' },
  { name: 'ross', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'phoebe', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'rachel', type: 'B' }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    '<th>Type A</th>',
    '<tr><td>monica</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>ross</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>phoebe</td></tr>',
    '<th>Type B</th>',
    '<tr><td>chandler</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>joey</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>rachel</td></tr>'
]
```

Expected Output if there is no Type A or no Type B:

```
[
    '<th>Type A</th>',
    '<tr><td>No Data for Type A</td></tr>'
    '<th>Type B</th>',
    '<tr><td>chandler</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>joey</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>rachel</td></tr>'
]
OR
[
    '<th>Type A</th>',
    '<tr><td>monica</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>ross</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>phoebe</td></tr>',
    '<th>Type B</th>',
    '<tr><td>No Data for Type B</td></tr>'
]
```

What I tried so far:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'monica', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'chandler', type: 'B' },
  { name: 'joey', type: 'B' },
  { name: 'ross', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'phoebe', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'rachel', type: 'B' }
]

const typeA     = [`
            <tr>
                <td>Type A</td>
            </tr>
`];
const typeB     = [`
            <tr>
                <td>Type B</td>
            </tr>
`];

arr.forEach( item => {
    if( item.type === 'A' ) {
            typeA.push(`
                <tr>
                    <td>${item.name}</td>
                </tr>
            `);
    }else if( item.type === 'B' ) {
            typeB.push(`
                <tr>
                    <td>${item.name}</td>
                </tr>
            `);
    }
});

const allData = [ ...typeA, ...typeB ];
console.log(allData);
```

Comment: it appears all you have to do is change the `<td>` for the _Type A/B_ to a `<th>` tag. Next, add `if()` statements for each `item.type` to see if there is a value in the `.name` property. Then you have your solution. Please recognize in the output the `\n` characters (whitespace) are preserved because of the template literal.

Comment: @RandyCasburn hey, did you mean I should change ```tr``` to ```th``` in typeA and typeB variable?

Comment: I-HMD has answered the question - @kern has answered more completely by adding the rendering code (since you pointed out you wanted to render this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "monica", type: "A" },
  { name: "chandler", type: "B" },
  { name: "joey", type: "B" },
  { name: "ross", type: "A" },
  { name: "phoebe", type: "A" },
  { name: "rachel", type: "B" },
];


// change to th!
const typeA = [
  "<th>Type A</th>"
];
// change to th!
const typeB = [
  "<th>Type B</th>"
];

if (!(arr.find(item=>item.type=='A'))) { typeA.push('<tr><td>No Data for Type A</td></tr>') }
if (!(arr.find(item=>item.type=='B'))) { typeB.push('<tr><td>No Data for Type B</td></tr>') }

arr.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.type === "A") {
    typeA.push(`<tr><td>${item.name}</td></tr>`);
  } else if (item.type === "B") {
    typeB.push(`<tr><td>${item.name}</td></tr>`);
  }
});

const allData = [...typeA, ...typeB];
console.log(allData);
```

Comment: Simple and precise. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should prepare your data first before thinking about rendering it.

If you try to do everything at the same moment, your code may be buggy and harder to maintain.

Format your data in a proper structure first, and then consume it.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'monica', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'chandler', type: 'B' },
  { name: 'joey', type: 'B' },
  { name: 'ross', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'phoebe', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'rachel', type: 'B' }
];

const types = {
    'A': [],
    'B': []
};

// Sort each item in the right type array
arr.forEach(item => {
    types[item.type].push(item);
});


// rendering time
let template = '';
// define a function to add a row in your template table
let add_row = content => `<tr><td>${content}</td></tr>`;
// loop through the keys of your object
for (let type in types) {
    template += `<th>Type ${type}</th>`;

    if (types[type].length === 0) {
        template += add_row(`No data for type ${type}`);
        continue;
    }
    // loop through the type items
    for (let item of types[type]) {
        template += add_row(item.name);
    }
}

document.querySelector('table').innerHTML = template;
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: hey man, thanks a lot for your solution. Learnt a lot from it. Wish I could choose both of these answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using a "groupBy" approach then iterating the `Object.entries()` of the grouped object

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'monica', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'chandler', type: 'B' },
  { name: 'joey', type: 'B' },
  { name: 'ross', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'phoebe', type: 'A' },
  { name: 'rachel', type: 'B' }
]

const grouped = arr.reduce((a,{type,...rest})=> (a[type].push(rest),a),{A:[],B:[]})
// helper function
const row = (txt, tag) => `<tr><${tag}>Type ${txt}</${tag}}></tr>`;

const res = Object.entries(grouped).reduce((a,[k,v])=>{   
   const rows = v.length ? v.map(o => row(o.name, 'td')) : [row('No Entries','td')]
   return  [...a, row(`Type ${k}`,'th'), ...rows];  
},[])

console.log(res)
```